# Removing i:type field in SOAP request generated by kSoap2 on Android

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2, android-ksoap2, ksoap

I already tried reading the internet about my issue, but I could not find the right information I need, so I try to explain my issue:

I am using kSoap2 to "talk" to a webservice over SOAP.
To generate my SOAP request I use the following code:

```
// Generate SOAP request XML
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(PUB_NAMESPACE,
"testSoapInterface");   

// Add request header
PropertyInfo requestHeader = new PropertyInfo();
requestHeader.setNamespace(PUB_NAMESPACE);
requestHeader.setName("requestheader");

// Generate username property
PropertyInfo usernameProp = new PropertyInfo();
usernameProp.setNamespace(BASE_NAMESPACE);
usernameProp.setName("username");
usernameProp.setValue(username);

// Generate applicationId property
PropertyInfo applicationIdProp = new PropertyInfo();
applicationIdProp.setNamespace(BASE_NAMESPACE);
applicationIdProp.setName("applicationId");
applicationIdProp.setValue("test");

// Add properties to requestHeader (nested)
requestHeader.setValue(new SoapObject(PUB_NAMESPACE, "requestheader")
.addProperty(usernameProp)
.addProperty(applicationIdProp));

request.addProperty(requestHeader);
```

Now, to serialize this, I use the following:

```
// Serialize SOAP request to the non .NET based SOAP server
SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
soapEnvelope.dotNet = false;
soapEnvelope.implicitTypes = true;
soapEnvelope.setAddAdornments(false);
soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
```

Because I am using nested soap (the requestheader consists of applicationId and username) I can imagine that this might be the cause.
I also have to use different namespaces for the different lines, which can also be a cause.

Can anybody help me on this??
Thanks!

Comment: Additional info: I am using kSoap 2.6.3 and I want to get rid of the i:type field in the generated start tag for the "requestheader".

Comment: @Niels_D..did you solve the problem..it would be great if you post a solution..

Answer (score 6):

You can use implicitTypes property of your envelope:

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.implicitTypes = true;
```

In this way the generated xml will not contain i:type.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same Problem, seems to be impossible to use PropertyInfo without generating any i:type with it. Nice solution would be to Override AddProperty(PropertyInfo pi) so it works on any case without the i:Type.

Got three solutions to offer:

## 1

If u dont need the Namespace then request.AddProperty(name,value) does it!

## 2

U could make your request header an own SoapObject, it wont use the "i:type".

```
SoapObject requestHeader = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"requestheader");
```

and in the last line

```
request.AddSoapObject(requestHeader);
```

## 3

For me it worked to set the Version of the SoapEnvelope to "VER10" since the types are ignored then. They're still in your request but ignored.
Replace:`SoapEnvelope.VER11` with:`SoapEnvelope.VER10`

Answer (score 0):

Where ever you are creating

```
 SoapSerializationEnvelope sEnvelop;
```

just assign `sEnvelop.implicitTypes = true;`

it will not create "i:type="d:string"" or "i:type="d:long"" inner datatype tag and web service can execute successfully